# How can I control the position in the admin menu of items added by plugins?

Tags: wp-admin

Having read elsewhere on Stack of two WP plugins forcing identical menu positions (with the likelihood of one then not appearing), I'm wondering how I can control the position of menu items added by plugins.

I already use a function which seems to handle such submenu items in 'settings', and another function to reorder default (posts, pages, themes, plugins, settings, etcetera) 'top level' items - but which doesn't change the positioning of such items added by plugins.

```
function custom_menu_order() {
return array(
//Add items here in desired order.

);
}

add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'menu_order', 'custom_menu_order' );
```

As an example, of the two top-level menu items added by WooCommerce, one appears above the item added by ContactForm7 and the other below, and it'd be nice to reorder them accordingly - and also, to be able to better reorder items which don't force a menu position and instead appear at the bottom.

I find it usually works fine for re-ordering default and 'edit.php?post_type=...' items, but those with 'admin.php?page=...' don't re-order.

When my re-order function is disabled, the two WooCommerce items ('edit.php?post_type=product', and 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order') group together as intended, but when the function is reactivated they're split by ContactForm7 ('admin.php?page=wpcf7').

And, one ('edit.php?post_type=shop_order') of the WooCommerce CPTs won't reorder - although the other ('edit.php?post_type=product') does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To change top level admin menu items order you'll need two `hooks`, two `filters`, and one `function`. Put the following code in your current theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_custom_menu_order( $menu_ord ) {
    if ( !$menu_ord ) return true;

    return array(
        'index.php', // Dashboard
        'separator1', // First separator
        'edit.php', // Posts
        'upload.php', // Media
        'link-manager.php', // Links
        'edit-comments.php', // Comments
        'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
        'separator2', // Second separator
        'themes.php', // Appearance
        'plugins.php', // Plugins
        'users.php', // Users
        'tools.php', // Tools
        'options-general.php', // Settings
        'separator-last', // Last separator
    );
}
add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'wpse_custom_menu_order', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'menu_order', 'wpse_custom_menu_order', 10, 1 );
```

The returned array of top level admin menu items, above, represents menu items inserted by core, in their default order. To include menu items added by plugins, we have to add them to this array. Let's say we have two plugins added and activated ( for example: `Wordfence` and `NextCellent Gallery` ). We have to find names of these menu items, first. When we click on `Wordfence`'s top level menu item, the resulting URL will end with `?page=Wordfence`. The part after `?page=` is our name ( `Wordfence` ). For `NextCellent Gallery`, the name will be `nextcellent-gallery-nextgen-legacy`. Now, let's add these items to our array:

```
return array(
    'index.php', // Dashboard
    'separator1', // First separator
    'edit.php', // Posts
    'upload.php', // Media
    'link-manager.php', // Links
    'edit-comments.php', // Comments
    'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
    'separator2', // Second separator
    'themes.php', // Appearance
    'plugins.php', // Plugins
    'users.php', // Users
    'tools.php', // Tools
    'separator3', // Third separator
    'options-general.php', // Settings
    'separator-last', // Last separator
    'Wordfence', // Wordfence
    'nextcellent-gallery-nextgen-legacy', // NextCellent Gallery
);
```

We can, now, move items of this array, up and down, to get the final order.

**Note**: you can use [Admin Menu Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) plugin, for easy drag and drop actions, as well.

Comment: @ Frank P. Walentynowicz ...thanks for the comprehensive answer. I updated my original post to clarify, and your suggestion of using 'the part after ?page=' is very helpful and solves my issue - except for one of the two WooCommerce items.

Comment: Quick addition to my above comment: I'd previously used Admin Menu Editor, but prefer a hardcoded function.

Comment: What is the significane of the 10,1? 
As in add_filter( 'menu_order', 'wpse_custom_menu_order', 10, 1 ); I cannot find any info on that. Probably something simple. But, I cannot get WooCommerce to budge and wondering if that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 22):

The existing answers are fine, but if you would add a new custom post type, you would have to re-edit those functions again and again.

To fix this, I developed this small function. Just define your `$new_positions` inside the `my_new_menu_order` function:

```
/**
 * Activates the 'menu_order' filter and then hooks into 'menu_order'
 */
add_filter('custom_menu_order', function() { return true; });
add_filter('menu_order', 'my_new_admin_menu_order');
/**
 * Filters WordPress' default menu order
 */
function my_new_admin_menu_order( $menu_order ) {
  // define your new desired menu positions here
  // for example, move 'upload.php' to position #9 and built-in pages to position #1
  $new_positions = array(
    'upload.php' => 9,
    'edit.php?post_type=page' => 1
  );
  // helper function to move an element inside an array
  function move_element(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $out = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    array_splice($array, $b, 0, $out);
  }
  // traverse through the new positions and move 
  // the items if found in the original menu_positions
  foreach( $new_positions as $value => $new_index ) {
    if( $current_index = array_search( $value, $menu_order ) ) {
      move_element($menu_order, $current_index, $new_index);
    }
  }
  return $menu_order;
};
```

Comment: This is awesome - so when new items are to be added as a menu item such as a custom post type (as you suggested) or a new plugin or even a new built-in option in the future it will get added just fine as normal?

Comment: @Brett It looks like it would work like that.

Comment: Still works a treat - thanks

Answer (score 17):

when you're creating a post type with register_post_type() you can set the menu position:

> menu_position
> (integer) (optional) The position in the menu order the post type should appear. show_in_menu must be true.
>
> ```
>     Default: null - defaults to below Comments 
>
>     5  - below Posts
>     10 - below Media
>     15 - below Links
>     20 - below Pages
>     25 - below Comments
>     59 - below first separator
>     60 - below Appearance
>     65 - below Plugins
>     70 - below Users
>     75 - below Tools
>     80 - below Settings
>     99 - below second separator
> ```

If items have the same menu position they are sorted alphabetically.

in your own plugin you can set the level.  if you're trying to change the menu position of a plugin you haven't created, many of them may have it pluggable, or you can to edit their calls.

Comment: @ rudtek... thanks. In my own CPTs I've avoided setting menu positions, preferring instead to use a menu re-order and thus 'have it all in the same place' and easier to subsequently change. Having no own plugins for which I'm trying to set menu position, it's for third-party plugins - for which I don't know enough about 'pluggable' or to edit their calls (which would presumably be overwritten on update).

Comment: Awesome, works fine

Comment: You can also use decimal numbers: 25.3

Comment: Wordpress core file source to back this answer up (and possibly update it if it changes with time): [/wp-admin/menu.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/menu.php)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to rassoh for a nice option.

Here is a revised version that contains a list of pages that should probably always stay at the top...

```
/**
 * These 2 filters and 1 function move the built in WordPress admin pages to
 * the top so they don't get pushed down the menu every time a new plugin is installed.
 * Activates the 'menu_order' filter and then hooks into 'menu_order'
 */
add_filter('custom_menu_order', function() { return true; });
add_filter('menu_order', 'my_new_admin_menu_order');
/**
 * Filters WordPress' default menu order
 */
function my_new_admin_menu_order( $menu_order ) {
  // define your new desired menu positions here
  // for example, move 'upload.php' to position #9 and built-in pages to position #1
  $new_positions = array(
    'index.php' => 1,  // Dashboard
    'edit.php' => 2,  // Posts
    'upload.php' => 3,  // Media
    'edit.php?post_type=page' => 4,  // Pages
    'edit-comments.php' => 5  // Comments
  );
  // helper function to move an element inside an array
  function move_element(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $out = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    array_splice($array, $b, 0, $out);
  }
  // traverse through the new positions and move 
  // the items if found in the original menu_positions
  foreach( $new_positions as $value => $new_index ) {
    if( $current_index = array_search( $value, $menu_order ) ) {
      move_element($menu_order, $current_index, $new_index);
    }
  }
  return $menu_order;
};
```